# Beginner here using c# and visual studio. I'm learning about for loops inside of for loops, and I'm unsure why it prints what it prints

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested

I don't have any errors in this code, I'm just wondering if someone could explain this in a simple way for me.

```
{

    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int k = 9; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            Console.Write(k + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

This prints

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

I was wondering what the simple explanation was for why it prints ten times, and what effect the original loop has on the second loop, sorry if this is too broad of a question, I'm just a little confused on why this works the way it does.
Thanks for taking the time to help out a beginner!

Comment: The inner loop prints the (descending) value of k ten times because going from 9 to 0 (included) requires ten loops. The outer loop just insert a carriagereturn and a newline every time the inner loop ends and then restart the inner loop (and this is done for 10 times as well).

Comment: Thanks! This really helped.

Comment: If you are wondering what the effect of the outer loop is, try varying the values. Start at `i=5` instead of `i=9` and/or continue until `i<3`, for instance. Maybe do a `Console.Write(i + ": ");` just before the k-loop, to make it clearer what happens with the `i`

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop controls how many times the inner loop will execute or the statements inside it.

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
```

In this loop we start at 9 and go backwards (i--) until we reach 0:
this is why you get the statements inside the outer loop to execute 10 times

The inner loop controls how many times the statements inside it will execute.

```
   for (int k = 9; k >= 0; k--) // again executes 10 times
   {
       Console.Write(k + " "); // this line gets executed with eah loop iteration
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It prints 10 times because you use >= 0, so 0 is counted as valid. 0 till 9 are 10 digits.
The k variable loop is responsile for the number of digits per line, the i variable loop is responsible for the amount of lines.
Step by step the operation looks like this:
Check if i is greater or equal as 0, true
Then check if k is greater or equal as 0, true
Print 9, subtract 1 from k.
Check if k is greater or equal as 0, true
Print 8, subtract 1 from k. Etc.
Because it is a for loop this will be done for k until k is mot anymore greater or equal to 0.

If this happens, only then you reach the point of the i variable for loop that says "subtract 1 from i" and the i loop is started again, which also starts the whole k loop again